# How to redirect using webpack proxy the dependencies of the redirected website?

Tags: redirect, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have two projects, one with documentation and one as the actual app.

When I access `http://localhost:3000/docs` my webpack setup is redirecting me to another server which is on `http://localhost:4000` and where the documentation lives.

The redirect is happening but when it tries to load dependencies (.js, .css) the request is made on the original port (3000) and not the port 4000.

How can I redirect the server requests for the second website?

My webpack setup:

```
proxy: {
  "/docs/**": {
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
      pathRewrite: { "^/docs": "" },
      changeOrigin: true,
      secure: false,
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you make it to localhost:4000 through the proxy nothing at the 4000 port is using '/docs' so the webpackDevServer doesn't think it needs to proxy anymore and resolves back to it's original port 3000. You haven't actually changed hosts in this scenario, so the origin is still 3000 unless webpackDevServer sees the '/docs' in the url. Might play around with the available router options. https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#options